# Python classmethod and(?) instancemethod

Tags: python

I have written a Python class for parsing a specialized text format.

```
class Parser(object):

   def __init__(self):
       # Initialize parser instance


   def parseFile(self , filename):
       pass

   def modifyParser(self , *args , **kwargs):
       pass 

   #Classmethod has same name as instance method - this does not work.
   @classmethod 
   def parseFile(cls , filename)
       parser = Parser( )
       return parser.parseFile( filename )
```

As indicated the parser can be modified with the `modifyParser` method - but in most cases I will just use the Parser instance as it comes from the `Parser.__init__()`. I would like to be able to do this:

```
# Parse file using 'custom' parser:
parser = Parser( )
parser.modifyParser( ... )
result = parser.parseFile("file.input")


# Parse using the default parser - do not explicitly instantiate an object:
result = Parser.parseFile("file.input")
```

This requires that the `parseFile( )` method can be called both as an instance method - with a `self` - and as a classmethod. Is this possible? Bad form?

Comment: IMO, I would skip the class method unless you had an absolute need for it, and just use `result = Parser().parseFile("file.input")`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I were you, I'd offer two distinct functions:

1. `mymodule.Parser().parseFile()` (instance method), and
2. `mymodule.parseFile()` (module-level function that uses the default instance).

This is what happens for example with the standard [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module, where you have `json.JSONDecoder().decode()` and `json.loads()`. Offering two distinct functions makes the code less ambiguous, more explicit and more predictable (in my opinion).

However, yes: what you want to do is possible. You have to implement your own [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) using `__get__`. Here's an example:

```
from functools import partial

class class_and_instance_method(object):

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        first_arg = obj if obj is not None else type
        return partial(self.func, first_arg)

class Parser(object):

    @class_and_instance_method
    def parseFile(self):
        if isinstance(self, type):
            print('using default parser')
        else:
            print('using the current instance')
```

```
>>> Parser.parseFile()
using default parser
```

```
>>> p = Parser()
>>> p.parseFile()
using the current instance
```

Comment: Yes - I see that the alternative with a module level function works - it does not sit nicely with my current scheme for imports++. I tried to look at the descriptor documentation - that was quite terse; do you have a three line tip?

Comment: @user422005: I provided an example

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use two separate names. In python due to it's dynamic nature there's no operator overloading as in C++, when one function has same name with different arguments.

When you say `def` in your script, you tell Python "set the following object(function object) to this name". So in your code you just redefine the name to reference `classmethod` and your instance method function object is lost.

Solution: use different names for instace method and class method.